# opening facebox in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebox

was wondering if anyone can help me open a facebox on a onChange from a drop down list. I have this so far.

```
<select><option value="www.google.com/" id="xxx"></option></select>
```

in the head i have

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(); 
    }); 
$(document).onchange(function() {
        $("xxx").facebox.open(); 
    });
/* ]]> */
```

p.s this is a striped down version

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not read the directions at the bottom of the page of their site? http://defunkt.io/facebox/ They show you how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bind

```
$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {
  $('#facebox .hero-link').click(function() { alert('click!'); });
});
```